# Why do so many Java questions involve java.util.Scanner?

Tags: discussion, questions

In my professional career (mostly pushing json around java middleware components, so not very broad I'll grant you) I have never come across or had a need to use `java.util.Scanner`.

Only in the last week or so having been an active member of SO for the first time have I starting seeing it pop up all over the place.

Can anyone explain to me why this is? Is it a common topic in University courses or something? Is it the bog standard java way of creating a command line app? (when I was writing command line apps I was learning in .NET land). Am I missing out on something great? What tasks can it achieve other than effectively splitting an input stream with a regex?

Comment: Yes, it's a common way to get input in CS courses.

Comment: Well.. When you were using .NET then I assume you used the console with `Console.Read()`? It's the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You guessed it. `Scanner` is taught in a ton of introductory Java courses. It's a very quick way to read user input from the command line. GUI programming isn't usually taught until later courses, so you'll see a lot of new programmers asking questions about `Scanner`.

Comment: Also from simple custom data files, like you may throw together for a homework assignment to feed it example data.

Comment: It's a very quick *and unfortunately error-prone* way to read user input :(